# Query another model and add reference before findOneAndUpdate insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model, DotaStats, that I'm trying to insert, or update, and find with findOneAndUpdate. New instances of that model are created this way, with upsert: true.

I've found out I can use virtuals for a lot of the computational stuff I want to do on this model, but the one thing I'm unsure of is how I can reference another model (without providing the _id) on new creation.

My use case is this way because I don't want to query the other model (the Game model) in every findOneAndUpdate request, as most of the time these requests will just be updated, and the Game reference won't have to be updated every time.

Here's my code. This is the model:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Game = require('../Game');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let schemaOptions = {
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
};

//NOTE: Validate URL!
let DotaStatsSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    game: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game',
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    rank: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    mmrEstimate: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    wins: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    losses: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    winPercentage: {
        type: Number
    },
    kills: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    deaths: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    assists: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    kda: {
        type: Number
    },
    secondsPlayed: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
}, schemaOptions);

DotaStatsSchema.virtual('winPercentage').get(() => {
    return (this.wins / (this.wins + this.losses) * 100) ? (this.wins / (this.wins + this.losses) * 100).toFixed(2) : 0;
})

DotaStatsSchema.virtual('kda').get(() => {
    return ((this.kills + this.assists) / this.deaths) ? ((this.kills + this.assists) / this.deaths).toFixed(2) : 0;
})

let DotaStats = module.exports = mongoose.model('DotaStats', DotaStatsSchema);
```

And here's where I'm calling findOneAndUpdate:

```
exports.handleDotaStats = (req, res, next) => {
    const newStats = {
        user: req.user._id,
        updatedAt: Date.now(),
        rank: req.body.rank,
        mmrEstimate: req.body.mmrEstimate,
        wins: req.body.wins,
        losses: req.body.losses,
        kills: req.body.kills,
        deaths: req.body.deaths,
        assists: req.body.assists,
        secondsPlayed: req.body.duration
    }

    DotaStats.findOneAndUpdate({
        user: req.user._id
    }, newStats, {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
        rawResult: true
    }).then((stats) => {
        return res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Dota stats created, or updated, and found.',
            stats: stats
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send(err)
    })
}
```

My understanding is that you can't use .pre('save') or .pre('validate') methods with findOneAndUpdate, so are there any options I have left, other than just querying every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Closing this, found a decent enough answer - using the rawResult (or passRawResult) option available in findOneAndUpdate, you can determine immediately after the request if the document has been upserted. That's good enough for now.